# how to reload js.rjs file using ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am building ruby on rails application. 
I have html partial that contains attribute of an object - @shout.content (text attribute).

In the controller Shout is -  @shout = Shout.last

The idea is that @shout changes every time a new shout is created (it changes to be the new shout).
I want that every 3 seconds the partial (that contains @shout.content)  will "refresh" using ajax.

I thought to put JavaScript function that will be repeated every 3 second:

```
setInterval( "updateShout()", 3000 );
```

And the updateShout() will run an js.rjs file that will do this:

```
page.replace_html('content', render(:partial => 'content', :locals => {:content => @shout.content}))
```

The missing part is the updateShout() function. I don't know how to execute js.rjs file using javascript.

Do you know how can I execute the js.rjs using javascript?

Thanks,

Oded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you (appear) to be using Prototype, you can simplify this greatly. First, instead of your call to `setInterval`, put this in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of your page:

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('content', '/path/to/shouts.js', { method: 'get', frequency: 3});
```

Ensuring that you replace `/path/to/shouts.js` with the appropriate URL. See [`periodicalUpdater`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/periodicalUpdater) for more details.

Then, instead of your RJS partial, all you need is the following in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :text => @shout.content }
end
```

This will render the text of the latest shout in the system and send it back to the browser, leaving PeriodicalUpdater to replace the text in the `content` div for you.

Comment: you don't need shout.js anymore. `/path/to/shouts.js` is simply the URL that maps to the function in your controller that has the `respond_to` block.

Answer (score -1):

You are just calling partials,you need to be fire an AJAX query to fetch record,and set ui as per requirement.If you are using jquery then fire AJAX request create js.erb file and called your partial that will generate required HTML,On successful request just update your DOM elements.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "<%= url %>"
     success: function(html){
          $("#content").html(html);
      }
   });
```